# Exclude a User From an Audit

Tags: sql-server, audit

I need to set up a SQL Server Audit to capture all database activity for all logins except one - the login our application runs under. In this case the login I want to exclude is `CPSDOM\cpointedb`.

In SQL Server Management Studio under 'Security / Logins' I see the login `CPSDOM\cpointedb`. But, when I look under 'Databases / dbName / Security / Users', I do not see the user `CPSDOM\cpointedb`.

When I set up my Database Audit Specification I also do not see a `CPSDOM\cpointedb` user. I was hoping to see this user listed in the Database Audit Specification so I could check all the users except that one.

Is there a different (better) way to do this? All I want to do is set up an audit that excludes one user.

I like the idea of just auditing all users (public) in the audit and excluding `CPSDOM\cpointedb` from the analysis, but I am concerned this may cause performance problems. Is that a valid concern?

Comment: How does CPSDOM\cpointedb have access to this specific database? Through role membership or AD group membership perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, I have to show my ignorance. I believe CPSDOM\cpointedb has access to the db because it shows up as a user under Security / Logins. Apparently it does not have to be explicitly identified as a user to the db.